# In Scheme, what's the point of "set!"?

Tags: scheme

What's the point of using the `set!` assignment operator in scheme? Why not just `rebind` a variable to a new value using `define`?

```
> (define x 100)
> (define (value-of-x) x) ;; value-of-x closes over "x"
> x
100
> (value-of-x)
100
> (set! x (+ x 1))
> x
101
> (value-of-x)
101
> (define x (+ x 1))
> x
102
> (value-of-x)
102
>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Though both `define` and `set!` will redefine a value when in the same scope, they do two different things when the scope is different. Here's an example:

```
(define x 3)

(define (foo)
  (define x 4)
  x)

(define (bar)
  (set! x 4)
  x)

(foo) ; returns 4
x     ; still 3
(bar) ; returns 4
x     ; is now 4
```

As you can see, when we create a new lexical scope (such as when we `define` a function), any names defined within that scope mask the names that appear in the enclosing scope. This means that when we `define`d `x` to `4` in `foo`, we really created a new value for `x` that shadowed the old value. In `bar`, since `foo` does not exist in that scope, `set!` looks to the enclosing scope to find, and change, the value of `x`.

Also, as other people have said, you're only supposed to `define` a name once in a scope. Some implementations will let you get away with multiple `define`s, and some won't. Also, you're only supposed to use `set!` on a variable that's already been `define`d. Again, how strictly this rule is enforced depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 7):

It is not usually permitted to `define` a variable more than once. Most REPLs allow it for convenience when you're trying things out, but if you try to do that in a Scheme program it will give you an error.

For example, in mzscheme, the program

```
#lang scheme
(define x 1)
(define x 2)
```

gives the error

```
test.ss:3:8: module: duplicate definition for identifier at: x in: (define-values (x) 2)
```

In addition, `define` has a different meaning when used inside of other contexts. The program

```
#lang scheme
(define x 1)
x
(let ()
  (define x 2)
  x)
x
```

has the output

```
1
2
1
```

This is because `define`s inside of certain constructs are actually treated as `letrec`s.

Answer (score 3):

When you use lexical bindings you do *not* `define` them:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (set! x (+ x 1))
  x)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use define you create a new variable with the new value, while the old variable still exists with the old value; it is just hidden by the new one. On the command line you don't see the difference to set!, but define won't be usable for e.g. a loop counter in an imperative program.

Comment: How would you design a loop counter in Scheme?

Comment: @RohitShinde bit late, but you have to accumulate the counter in the function signature. A loop per se is non existent in Scheme, but recursive functions are. So you can use recursive functions to make a loop, and to make a "loop" counter you'd need to have your counter in the parameter list of your function. And everytime you make a recursive call you just decrement your counter first. The keyword here is "accumulative recursion"